# image button event not fired in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am using the below code to validate and process some other action. In the script, i check the balance amount and pay amount.Pay amount not exceed the balance amount means it return the error message. Then the else part doesn't redirect to my code behind button click event. i can't find it. Please help me to solve this.

```
 if (ddl_selected == "ebal") {
    var cust_balance = document.getElementById('<%= lbl_balance.ClientID %>');
    var cust_ramount = document.getElementById('<%= lbl_amount.ClientID %>');

            if (cust_balance.innerHTML <= cust_ramount .innerHTML) {
                alert('Error Alert : You don\'t have enough balance.!.');
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }

        }

   <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_activate" runat="server" OnClick="btn_pay_Click"
     OnClientClick="return valid_details();"
     ImageUrl="~/Images/pay.png" />

protected void btn_pay_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
  //Event not fire 
}
```

Comment: you need to enable postback on that button control.

Comment: set `AutoPostBack` property value to `true` in the button

Comment: @VigneshNatraj How can i enable the postback in button.

Comment: Image button doesn't allow the property AutoPostBack

Comment: @user2110618, you don't need to enable postback, `onclick` event is  postback event. Did you make sure that js function is returning `true`? Add alert statement and check if it is executing else part. Also change `ImageClickEventArgs` to `EventArgs`

Comment: make sure your clientside javascript returns true, else the postback will not happen.

Comment: How can i check the return value.

Comment: @user2110618, add `alert("true");` in your else part before `return true;` statement. Can you post complete code for this function - `valid_details()`

Comment: @user2110618 javasacript code inside the same aspx page ??

Answer (score 0):

Change

`OnClientClick="javascript:valid_details();return true;"` instead of

```
OnClientClick="return valid_details();"
```

Comment: I think OP wants to validate, stop and alert user on error, your code will always validate true and continue.

Comment: No.My code was used for hit button click event in only allowed for else part.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
OnClientClick="javascript:return valid_details();
instead of
OnClientClick="return valid_details();